# Connection between the three Atzeret?

Tags: passover, commentaries, sukkot, shavuos, shmini-atzeres

I noticed that there are three moments called Atzeret.

1. The seventh day of Pesach ([Deuteronomy 16:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.16.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
2. Shavuot ([Pesachim 68b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.68b.9-12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
3. Shemini Atzeret ([Leviticus 23:36](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.36?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

But what is the connection between these three specific moments?:

Although all three are called Atzeret the one of Pesach is a 'seven' celebration, Shavuot a 'eight after seven' celebration, and Shemini a 'eight' celebration.

Although connected to Sukkot Shemini Atzeret isn't one of the Shalosh Regalim, while Pesach and Shavuot Are.

Although Pesach was necessary in order for us to receive the Torah, only Shavuot (Matan Torah) and Shemini Atzeret (Simchat Torah) celebrate Torah.

Although it's been said that the relationship of Shemini Atzeret to Sukkot is the same as that of Shavuot  to Passover. Pesach shevi'i is a Atseret, but the shevi'i of Sukkot isn't.
Besides the Atzeret of Pesach (Shavuot) comes after 7x7+1 and the Atzeret of Sukot after 7+1...

I can think of so many connections, but none of these seem to fit all three moments. Is there a connection between Pesach, Shavuot and Sukkot (in any order taken)?

I have the impression I'm missing or overlook some things to connect this properly. Please help me out..

Comment: "Atzeret" means "stop." The seventh day of Pesach is the "stop" to Pesach. Shavuot is the "stop" to Sefirat HaOmer. Shemini Atzeret is the "stop" to Sukkot. So there is a connection, and it's a lot more simple than you're making it.

Comment: @ezra But that's based on the point all three are called atzeret, not based on these moadim themselves

Comment: @ezra P.s. I didn't want to put Rashi or Hirsch in here who also make a connection based on the fact these are called atzeret. I was just looking for another connection based on these moadim of pesach, shavuot and Shemini Atzeret.

Comment: Shemini Atzeret is also a Regel. (Whether or not you want to view it as part of the Regel of Sukkot or its own Regel.)

Comment: Like Passover and Shavuot, Sukkot has a dual significance: historical and agricultural. Historically, Sukkot commemorates the forty-year period during which the children of Israel were wandering in the desert, living in temporary shelters. Agriculturally, Sukkot is a harvest festival and is sometimes referred to as Chag Ha-Asif, the Festival of Ingathering. So in this case Sukkot is also connected to Pesach and Shavuot, just like Shemini Atzeret is.

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe a strange question, but we take the whole Pesach as a regel, all the days untill the atzeret, likewise we take the whole Sukkot as a regel untill the atzeret... we do take Shavuot untill it's Atzeret.. but why isn't the sefirat ha'omer which is the cycle that ends, stops etc at Shavuot?

Comment: I must have read [Devarim 16:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0516.htm#8) over a thousand times, and with all the talk around comparing _Shemini ha-Atzeret_ with _Shavu'ot_, I didn't notice _Shevi'i shel Pesach_ was also called an _Atzeret_. Thanks, Levi.

Comment: @Levi, to go one step further, you could also have said that the public Torah reading for these three Chagim (Shemini Atseret, 8th day of Pesach and 2nd day of Shavuos) in Chuts Laaretz is the same - Kol Habechor (or Aser Teaser if Shabbos). What's the connection between these three times that our Sages decided to set up the same Torah reading? One more question to consider to answer our questions is, why do we read on Shemini Atseret the Aser Teaser/Kol Habechhor portion in C.L. since that Chag is not even mentioned in the Torah portion?

Comment: here's a book on the topic https://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%A2%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%AA.html?id=hSgjNQEACAAJ

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi S. R. Hirsch notes the similarity of עצרת to אוצר, and says that the two biblical עצרת instances are both at the end of the festival, so the point is to collect the thoughts and lessons of the entire festival on the last day.

שבועות is also the culmination of the entire period including פסח and ספירת העומר, hence the rabbinical appelation of עצרת as well.

Answer (score 0):

Azeret means an assembly. So just like the last day of Sukkot is called at Sarah it and it was a gathering of all the Jewish people and also a kohelet is in the sanctification of the bet hamikdash h in the time of  Shlomo hanelech. 
You can also say that there is no greater atzeret then the giving of the Torah. Additionally we also see that on the second day of Passover we are commanded to read the O'Mara and its fulfillment ends the very day before the holiday of Shavuot which would be in some way an azeret  to the holiday of Passover

Comment: please fix spelling so you can be understood